# interact 2 radio buttons 2 different functions Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have two radio buttons that i have changed to clickable images using `label`, working great.
The problem is, when one label is checked, the second is not unchecked.

Here is the code of the 2 functions :

```js
var $radioButtons = $('input[value="2"]');
$radioButtons.click(function() {
    $radioButtons.each(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('checked11', this.checked);
    });
});
    
    var $2radioButtons = $('input[value="5"]');
$2radioButtons.click(function() {
    $2radioButtons.each(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('checked12', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: Share your html as well

Comment: please provide sample html that your code references. You aren't changing class of the opposite radio

Comment: Radio buttons are interlinked when they have the same value in the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to interlink the radio buttons. You do this by giving them a `name` attribute. In the example I've added two sets of radio buttons. I changed the selector of the jQuery function to select on the `name` attribute. The `name` attribute can be the same for multiple elements in contradiction to the `id` attribute that must be unique throughout the entire document. So you can use this to your advantage when selecting elements using jQuery.

*Solution:*

> It seems you rely on the `checked` attribute of the radio to toggle the classes. To make a set of radios work they must be grouped by the same name.

In this example the `background-color` switches between the `grouped` radio buttons. Green for group 1 and red for group 2. I left your functions intact, only changed the selector. The HTML in this solution is there to cope with the `parent().parent()` selecting you do. This can also be improved. jQuery's `parent` accepts selectors.

```js
var $radioButtons = $('input[name="radiogaga"]');
$radioButtons.click(function() {
  $radioButtons.each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('checked11', this.checked);
  });
});

var $2radioButtons = $('input[name="radioblabla"]');
$2radioButtons.click(function() {
  $2radioButtons.each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('checked12', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
.checked11 {
  background-color: lime;
}
.checked12 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <span> 
  <label for="radio1" >This is radio 1</label>
  <input name="radiogaga" value="2" type="radio" id="radio1" />  
</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
  <label for="radio2" >This is radio 2</label>
  <input name="radiogaga" value="3" type="radio" id="radio2" />
    </span>
</div>

<div>

  <span> 
  <label for="radio3" >This is radio 3</label>
  <input name="radioblabla" value="4" type="radio" id="radio3" />  
</span>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <span>
  <label for="radio4" >This is radio 4</label>
  <input name="radioblabla" value="5" type="radio" id="radio4" />
    </span>
</div>
```